# Is it audacious and false to encapsulate Descartes Philosophy in this one simple sentence?

Tags: descartes, dualism, rationalism

Namely: "I, therefore God, therefore body and mind". I want to see if I understand the bigger picture of his Philosophy.

Comment: Yes, a little bit too audacious...

Answer (score 2):

I think it is quite audacious, but I don't think it is inherently and necessarily false. I say this because there has been multiple interpretations that seem to have different understandings of Descartes' philosophy and I think it is open for different takes and interpretations. I think it is audacious because it is extremely reductive and leaves out words that have ontological attributes like existing and being/'is'. You should understand that Descartes' cogito philosophy/argument, which I think you are referring to, (even though you haven't explicitly mentioned) is usually taken from a metaphysical and ontological perspective.

In general though, it seems to me that your interpretation is following what is historically accepted that Descartes' meditations regarding the cogito is that it goes from establishing his own existence, to a good God and then to his body, mind and then the rest of the observable/experiencable world.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I want to include it as a deliberately banal sentence in my introduction to a certain topic in my essay. I wanted it's nature to be simple, short and even audacious, because I used extensive amount of words for a small essay.